# Google App Engine get_current_user always return None, even if i'm logged

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

here's my code

```
 def subscribe_current_user(self):
        user1 = SocialNodeSubscription(parent=self.key)
        user1.subscribed = True
        current_user = users.get_current_user()
        logging.error(current_user)
        if current_user:
            user1.user=current_user
        else:
            raise users.UserNotFoundError

        user1.put()
```

The problem is that get_current_user returns None even if i'm logged in. It stores a None in the field user1.user and it prints a None in the log console.

How can i solve that?

Comment: try without parent=self.key..

Answer (score 1):

Do you have `login: required` defined in app.yaml for your handler or have you provided a login url using `users.create_login_url()` so that the user can explicitly login.

Even if you are logged into google somewhere, users.get_current_user() won't
return a user object.

Comment: I'm working on an already developed project and when get_current_user() is called anywhere else in the code, is not associated with login: required, that actually is never used in the app.yaml

Comment: It worked, but still is not exactly what i need. I need the user to be able to see the page without logging in and render it according to the user being logged in on not.

Comment: ok, so you need to have given the user a login page - use users.create_login_url()  once they login then even an unprotected page will give you the user.  The distinction here is the user has logged into your app rather than google in general.  See https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/users/loginurls  for more details.

Comment: This is misleading: A handler does not need to have `login: required` in order to have `users.get_current_user()` defined - the user just has to have logged in for this app (as you point out, being logged into their Google account alone isn't sufficient).

Answer (score 1):

I have seen a lot of similar questions.

It helps to think of this line differently...

user = users.get_current_user()

This line doesn't search high and low in your browser and cache and retrieve whatever info and put it into a nice user object; it simply checks if an user is logged in to the app using the users class. Which means if you did not have the user logged with the users class, chances are this line of code won't do what you want it to do.

The important codes that should usually follow a get_current_user() method:

```
if user:
        greeting = ('Welcome, %s! (<a href="%s">sign out</a>)' %
                    (user.nickname(), users.create_logout_url('/')))
    else:
        greeting = ('<a href="%s">Sign in or register</a>.' %
                    users.create_login_url('/'))

self.response.out.write('<html><body>%s</body></html>' % greeting)
```

Answer (score 0):

I believed, you surely importing this,

**from google.appengine.api import users**

And also, Are you really authenticating django's 'User' model at the time of login?