# Get the current user from BlobstoreUploadHandler

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-endpoints

I want to get the current user from BlobstoreUploadHandler. I'm using endpoints for my web application, but (outside of Endpoints) I built /uploadUrl to upload files to the Blobstore.

The image uploads correctly. So, I need to link the image uploaded to the user, but **users.get_current_user() returns None**. On the frontend side the user is logged using OAuth2. Any idea for this issue?

If I use endpoints.get_current_user() raise an error:

> No valid endpoints user in environment

This is my code:

```
class UploadHandler(blobstore_handlers.BlobstoreUploadHandler):
    def post(self):
        upload_files = self.get_file_infos()
        file_info = upload_files[0]

        gcs_filename = file_info.gs_object_name
        file_key = blobstore.create_gs_key(gcs_filename)

        File(file=gcs_filename, owner=users.get_current_user() ).put()
```

Answer (score 0):

in your app.yaml you have to add `login: required` or `login: admin`.

Example:

```
handlers:
- url: /upload_handler.*
  script: my_app.media_handlers.application
  login: required
```

After this, `users.get_current_user()` should work.

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig#Python_app_yaml_Requiring_login_or_administrator_status

Other thread about this:[Google App Engine get_current_user always return None, even if i'm logged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11373966/google-app-engine-get-current-user-always-return-none-even-if-im-logged)

Comment: Lepi, yes I did. But now says "Request failed because URL requires user login". But user is logged from OAuth2. What I can do?

Comment: Were you using `login:admin` or `login:required`? If it is admin, then ensure that you are an admin to this app not just a simple user. If you are using simple `login:required` then I have no other ideas right now.

Answer (score 0):

Each App requires its own login, and every class needs to have users imported and declared if you want to use User class in the code.

from google.appengine.api import users
import webapp2

```
class MyHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        user = users.get_current_user()
        if user:
            greeting = ('Welcome, %s! (<a href="%s">sign out</a>)' %
                        (user.nickname(), users.create_logout_url('/')))
        else:
            greeting = ('<a href="%s">Sign in or register</a>.' %
                        users.create_login_url('/'))

        self.response.out.write('<html><body>%s</body></html>' % greeting)
```

For more details please see this article - https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/users/